How to setup WxWidgets IntelliSense on linux VS code
how to get WxWidgets IntelliSense for Linux VScode. i was able successfully compile WxWidgets.
i added '/home/udan/Documents/Libraries/wxWidgets/include' to include path, but that doesn't seems to work. then i got suggestion '/usr/local/include/wx-3.2' to add to include path that doesn't work either.

@udaanjayanth, build minimal sample and see what directories are included there...

Also - did you build the library yourself? Or used he one from the repo? In a former cae - did you install it?

i installed it. do you know how to add WxWidgets IntelliSense to vs code

Jayanith, there is some mixed path. First of - did you get the source code and build it or you installed it from the repository? I presume the former.Also you should be consistent in your path - either use /usr/local/include or your home directory.

add these location to include path.
/usr/local/include/wx-3.2
/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.2
